# UWP: WebView on Raspberry in english and not german

Tags: webview, uwp, raspberry-pi3

I'm developing an UWP for desktop, mobile and IOT (Raspberry) devices. It runs perfectly on every device. But on the Raspberry I have the problem, that the webview olways opens the english site of our company website.

At the configuration of the Windows IOT on the Raspberry I've set the language and the keyboard to German.

So I don't know why it doesn't work.

As an workaround I'll try to set the website-open-language of the webview to german. But I don't find such a property.

Has anyone a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "Accept-Language" header using `NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage` and send along e.g "de-DE" (I think this is the right ISO code for for German) and see if that resolves the problem

Comment: That's it! Thank you!